# How to search through HashMap with 2-dimensional int array as key

Tags: java

I have a lot of two-dimensional integer arrays (size 8x8), which each have some numerical double value based on a calculation. I would like to store them in a data structure, so I would be able to look up a two-dimensional array and check what value I have given that array earlier.

I have been trying to use a hashCode of the two-dimensional arrays, that did not work.
I have also tried a hashMap with the array as key and I have tried to create custom objects as keys. But neither worked out for me, so I am doing something wrong. Where do I find the solution?

Comment: If your 2D arrays are small, consistently sized and not [jagged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array), you’ll get much better performance by using a 1D array and accessing the “internal” arrays by offset

Comment: *"But neither worked out for me"* Then edit the question and **show us** what you've tried, so we can help you figure out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java arrays do not override `hashCode()` and `euqals()` from `Object` native implementation they are not really suitable for lookups. For example two identical arrays are not equal:

```
int[][] a1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
int[][] a2 = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
System.out.println(a1.hashCode()); // 1277181601
System.out.println(a2.hashCode()); // 41903949
System.out.println(a1.equals(a2)); // false
```

One can however create a wrapper class that internally uses `Arrays.deepHashCode()` and `Arrays.deepEquals()` as follows:

```
public class IntIntArray {
  private int[][] values;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    IntIntArray that = (IntIntArray) o;
    return Arrays.deepEquals(value, that.value);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.deepHashCode(value);
  }
}
```

This class is suitable for value based lookups and can be used as `Map` key:

```
IntIntArray i1 = new IntIntArray(new int[][] {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}});
IntIntArray i2 = new IntIntArray(new int[][] {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}});
System.out.println(i1.hashCode()); // 30729379
System.out.println(i2.hashCode()); // 30729379
System.out.println(i1.equals(i2)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

If the you're using the **SAME INSTANCE** of the arrays, you can just use them as the key without doing anything:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    Integer[][] arr = new Integer[8][];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        arr[i-1] = new Integer[] {545*i,237*i,3513*i,461*i,465*i,20*i,134*i,352*i};
    }

    Map<Integer[][], Double> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(arr, 5.7);
    Double val = map.get(arr);

    assert val == 5.7;
}
```

You can see here that getting the value from the map, using the same array that was used to put it, will return the wanted value.

This is because the implementation of the array of hash-code and equals is to check of the same instance, which is also good performance, if that is your case.

However, if you have different instances of the same array (key) it won't work:

```
@Test
public void test2() {
    Integer[][] arr1 = new Integer[8][];
    Integer[][] arr2 = new Integer[8][];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        arr1[i-1] = new Integer[] {545*i,237*i,3513*i,461*i,465*i,20*i,134*i,352*i};
        arr2[i-1] = new Integer[] {545*i,237*i,3513*i,461*i,465*i,20*i,134*i,352*i};
    }

    Map<Integer[][], Double> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(arr1, 5.7);
    Double val = map.get(arr2);

    assert val == null;
}
```

Instead, you'll need to create a "Key" object and implement equals and hash code for it:

```
class MyKey {
    Integer[][] arr;

    public MyKey(Integer[][] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyKey myKey = (MyKey) o;
        return Arrays.deepEquals(arr, myKey.arr);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.deepHashCode(arr);
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
@Test
public void test2() {
    Integer[][] arr1 = new Integer[8][];
    Integer[][] arr2 = new Integer[8][];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        arr1[i-1] = new Integer[] {545*i,237*i,3513*i,461*i,465*i,20*i,134*i,352*i};
        arr2[i-1] = new Integer[] {545*i,237*i,3513*i,461*i,465*i,20*i,134*i,352*i};
    }

    Map<MyKey, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(new MyKey(arr1), 5.7);
    Double val = map.get(new MyKey(arr2));

    assert val == 5.7;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using an array, use a `List<List<Integer>>` and use a map with hashCode as keys. As per the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode()) you should get the same value everytime if the values in the list are same. The hashCode is calculated by the following.

```
int hashCode = 1;
  Iterator<E> i = list.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
      E obj = i.next();
      hashCode = 31*hashCode + (obj==null ? 0 : obj.hashCode());
  }
```

It also mentions that

> This ensures that `list1.equals(list2)` implies that
>   `list1.hashCode()==list2.hashCode()` for any two lists, `list1` and `list2`,
>   as required by the general contract of `Object.hashCode()`.

Comment: For `List<List<Integer>>`, the hashcode is calucated as `list.hashCode()`.

Comment: *"use a map with hashCode as keys"* Why not use the `List<List<Integer>>` itself as the key? Remember, hashcodes are not guaranteed to be unique, so if you only use hashcode as key you'll have clashes.

Comment: @Andreas The HashMap uses the `hashCode()` method to hash the objects. So both are same. Without hashCodes, there is no way you can maintain a Map in Java.

Comment: I know that, but if your key is the `List`, the map can have two different lists with the same hashcode. If your key is just the hashcode, not the list itself, you cannot have two different lists that happen to have the same hashcode.

Comment: @Andreas The map cannot have two lists with the same hashcode. From the documentation: "For example, the specification for the `containsKey(Object key)` method says: "`returns true` if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key k such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`."" The `equals` method compares the `hashCode`. So you cannot hash two different lists with the same hashcode as a key in a `Map` in java. More info [here] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: *"The `equals` method compares the `hashCode`"*. No it doesn't. Where did you get that idea? You should try reading the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`List.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: In this case, these are integer objects, so it is the `hashCode` that is being compared. And I know what javadoc is as I have been referencing them the whole time.

Comment: Still, a `HashMap` can store two keys that are not `equals()`, even if they have the same `hashCode()`, so keying by hashcode only will not allow two unequal *object* to be used as keys. Use the *object* as the key, not its hashcode.